# Convergence of vector spaces

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, definition

I'm considering vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ : $(E_n)_n$ is a sequence of vector space (all included in $\mathbb{R}^p$ for example, with $p$ fixed). What meaning(s) do we usually give to :

- $E_n$ converges to $E$ a vector space of $\mathbb{R}^p$.

Does the dimension of $E_n$ then converge to $\text{dim} E$?

Comment: If $p$ is finite, then after a  while all the $E_n$ are $E$.

Comment: Could you provide a definition of convergence and explain your statement @AndréNicolas? It means that $\left\{ (x,y), x=1/n y \right\}$ can't converge to $\left\{ (x,y), x=0 \right\}$ for example?

Comment: A useful definition of convergence of a sequence of **sets** has been given in the answer by Dalamar below. Under that definition (or any sensible other) the comment  made above holds.

Comment: Ok, so there is no notion of convergence of vector spaces but only more general definitions (and Dalamar gave me one) of sets and for this definition, there is no way the sequence of vector spaces that I gave in my previous comment converges to $\left\{ (x,y), x=0 \right\}$.

Comment: On second thought, it is not so clear to me that one cannot find a suitable definition under which for example if $u$ is close to $v$, then the space of multiples of $u$ is close to the space of multiples of $v$. Will write if I come up with something reasonable.

Comment: Ok thank you, but if the answer is that, whatever the definition you take, a convergent sequence of vector spaces is constant (up to a certain rank), I understand why I haven't seen this more often.

Answer (score 2):

I am not really an expert, but you might use the following notion of convergence:
a sequence $(F_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ of non-empty closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^m$ is said to converge to another non-empty closed subset of $F$ of $\mathbb{R}^m$ if 
$$ \lim_{j \to \infty} \sup_{x \in F_j \cap B(0,r)} \operatorname{dist}(x,F)=0$$
AND 
$$ \lim_{j \to \infty} \sup_{x \in F \cap B(0,r)} \operatorname{dist}(x,F_j)=0$$
for all $r>0$. Of course the suprema are understood to vanish when $F_j \cap B(0,r)$ and $F \cap B(0,r)$ are empty. This is used often in the context of metric spaces. You can find further info e.g. in Fractured Fractals and Broken Dreams by Semmes.

Comment: Could you tell me more precisely where to look in your reference?

Comment: Chapter 8, convergence of metric spaces. Page 52-53. I believe sometimes this also goes by the name of Gromov-Hausdorff convergence.